# Regexp/config var for apt-cacher to allow repo files for 16.04 clients (Metadata, Components-*.yml)?

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04, apt-cacher

I use `apt-cacher` on a Debian server, and doing an `apt-get update` with a 16.04 client I'm finding that it's blocking a bunch of repo files including `icons-64x64[.tar[.gz]]`, some `xz` extensions, `Metadata` and `Components-*.yml`.

I've managed to update the following variables on my `/etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf` to allow some of the file types through, but I'm still stuck on the `Metadata` and `Components-*.yml` files.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` has been cut down to a single line for testing:

```
deb http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

apt-cacher excerpts:

```
index_files_regexp = ^(?:Index(?:\.bz2)?|Packages(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz)?|Release(?:\.gpg)?|InRelease|Sources(?:\.gz|\.bz2)?|Contents-(?:[a-z]+-)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.gz|(?:srclist|pkglist)\.[a-z-]+\.bz2|release(?:\.gz|\.bz2)?|Translation-[a-z]{2,3}(?:_[A-Z]{2})?(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz)?)$
installer_files_regexp = ^(?:vmlinuz|linux|initrd\.gz|changelog|NEWS.Debian|UBUNTU_RELEASE_NAMES\.tar\.gz(?:\.gpg)?|icons-64x64\.tar\.gz(?:\.tar)?|(?:Devel|EOL)?ReleaseAnnouncement(?:\.html)?|meta-release(?:-lts)?(?:-(?:development|proposed))?)$
```

The error:

```
# apt-get update
Get:1 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [116 kB]
Get:2 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,436 kB]
Get:3 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,431 kB]
Get:4 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [732 kB]
Ign:5 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:6 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [414 kB]
Get:7 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [10.5 kB]
Get:8 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages [10.8 kB]
Get:9 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [3,420 B]
Ign:10 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:5 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  403  Forbidden
Err:10 http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  403  Forbidden
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  403  Forbidden
W: Failed to fetch http://aptmirror:3142/au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried inserting the expression `Components-(?:[a-z]+-)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.yml` and `Metadata` in a few different places in the above variables, without any luck.

Can anyone help me get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got an `apt-cacher` on vivid. Had to change in `/etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf`:

```
ubuntu_release_names = dapper, edgy, feisty, gutsy, hardy, intrepid, jaunty, karmic, lucid, maverick, natty, oneiric, precise, quantal, raring, saucy, trusty, utopic, vivid, wily, xenial

index_files_regexp = ^(?:Index(?:\.bz2)?|(?:Sources|Packages|release)(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz)?|Release(?:\.gpg)?|InRelease|Contents-(?:[a-z]+-)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.gz|(?:srclist|pkglist)\.[a-z-]+\.bz2|Translation-[a-z]{2,3}(?:_[A-Z]{2}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?)?(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz|\.lzma)?|Components-[a-z0-9]+\.yml(?:\.gz|\.bz2)?|icons-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.tar(?:\.gz)?)$
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me really close - I ended up explicitly appending 'icons-64x64.tar' to the end because for whatever reason your regexp wasn't matching that. It's close enough for me ;)

Comment: This regex works for me.
I made a miss in my copy paste of the regex (because it's long) so maybe it was your case too and you were missing the end. But for me, this regex works perfectly!

Comment: BTW, is there a bug report on this? It's pretty serious.
I'm using it as a hobbyist, but for organizations, it could break things badly…

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with apt-cacher-ng from ubuntu 12.04 when trying to use my mirror with ubuntu 16.04 clients.

Canonical pushed an updated package that fix the problem without any additional configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add `(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz)?`
on to the end of the expression you inserted. On my nearest mirror, the only `*.yml` files are actually `*.yml.gz`.

My install of `apt-cacher-ng` was having the same problem, modifying it's regexp in the way you mentioned (with addition, the syntax was also slightly different) solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using debmirror on a Netgear ReadyNAS to mirror 16.04 and came across this problem. My current "fix" (jury is still out on that) was to copy /usr/bin/debmirror from a 16.04 machine onto the NAS as it's only a Perl script and more recent versions of debmirror have a fix for this issue if I've correctly researched the problem.